# Using the OnTextChanged TextBox event isn't working

Tags: asp.net

I have a repeater that places 600+ textboxes filled with data on my page.
A typical user will edit several of these.

I would like the OnTextChanged event to run when I hit a save button, but it's not working.

All of my textboxes have the property `OnTextChanged="TextBoxChanged"`
When my user selects the save button

```
<asp:Button ID="SaveChangesBtn" CssClass="SaveAndNextBtn" runat="server" 
            Text="Save Changes" onclick="SaveChangesBtnClick" />
```

I would like the TextBoxChanged event to run for each textbox that has been changed.
How can I implement this?

Comment: Is the `TextChanged` event raised only once after you've clicked the button?

Comment: I have no textchanged anywhere. I just have the TextBoxChanged function that is never called

Comment: Do you rebind the repeater on every postback or have you wrapped the databinding stuff (as you should) in a `!IsPostback`-check?

Comment: That actually did the trick. I didn't know about that. Thanks! Please make your comment an answer so I can select it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you rebind the repeater on every postback or have you wrapped the databinding stuff (as you should) in a !IsPostback-check?

```
if(!IsPostBack)
    DataBindRepeater();
```

If you databind web-databound controls on postbacks, all changes are lost and events won't be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid OnTextChanged isn't quite what you are looking for then. OnTextChanged fires after a control has been entered, changed and then left (lost focus), so it fires when you select the next object.

you could use the OnTextChanged to accumulate a list of the IDs of the textboxes with changed contents, and then when you save, just loop over all the changed boxes to perform whatever task you like.

Comment: Only true with `AutoPostBack` (not default). Otherwise the `OnTextChanged` event handler would be called on the next postback(.f.e on button click).

Comment: It actually seems to be only calling the TextBoxes on the save button now. I'm not sure why it isn't calling it out of focus, but I'm not complaining because this is the way I want it.

Comment: @proseidon: That's what i've commented above, only if you set `AutoPostBack="True"` it will post back immediately as soon as the user has changed the `Text` and the focus is lost(javascript blur event). But the serverside `TextChanged` event is triggered anyway later on the next roundtrip to server.